# Time change after suspension

Tags: 20.04, suspend, time

After I on my laptop after suspending, the time automatically changes and shows a wrong time. But once I restart and boot back it gets normal until I suspend again. I use a HP pavilion, with ubuntu version 20.04.3. The time gets forawrded by around 4 to 5 hours

Comment: A little more information will be needed to offer some help here. Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) the version of Ubuntu you're running (2) the brand and model of computer you're using (3) how wrong the time is (one hour fast, 30 minutes slow, etc.). With this information, it may be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: I have edited. Please have a look

Comment: Do you live in a UTC-5:00 time zone, either in North or South America? Do you have a dual-boot system between Ubuntu and Windows? This sounds like a hardware clock issue 

Comment: I live in India, Yes dual boot between ubuntu and windows

Comment: Some parts of India are UTC+5:30 if memory serves, so this sounds like a hardware clock issue. You may be able to resolve this with a simple command: `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock`

Comment: I have tried this one, it is a temporary solution. but when I put to suspend and open, it gets forwarded again